# Spotify: post to api/token gives bad request but works in curl

Tags: java, spotify

I'm trying to get an access token from the spotify web api through the [Authorization Code Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization_code_flow). When doing the request in curl, it gives me back the token as expected:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic Mj...zk=" -d grant_type=authorization_code -d code=AQ...Ew -d redirect_uri=http://localhost:8081/callback https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
```

However, when I try to do the same request in java code, I get a 400 bad request:

```
    final String url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";

    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", req.getParameter("code")));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri ", "http://localhost:8081/callback"));


    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
    httpPost.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,"Basic " +  Base64.encodeBase64String(("2...0" + ":" + "4...9").getBytes()));
    httpPost.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
    System.out.println(response);
```

This is the error response I get:

```
HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [Server: nginx, Date: Fri, 06 Oct 2017 21:20:39 GMT, Content-Type: application/json, Content-Length: 68, Connection: keep-alive, Keep-Alive: timeout=600] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: application/json,Content-Length: 68,Chunked: false]}}
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Can't you output your text to a string before you send it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it myself by using a StringEntity instead of the UrlEncodedFormEntity:

```
    final String url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    httpPost.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpPost.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + Base64.encodeBase64String(("2...0" + ":" + "4...9").getBytes()));
    StringEntity data = new StringEntity("grant_type=authorization_code&&code=" + req.getParameter("code") + "&&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8081/callback");
    httpPost.setEntity(data);

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: Dude! That's a huge difference than what one would expect. Thank you so much for this!